# Cannot get second screen on Kali Linux (Lenovo Legion 5 with Nvidia RTX)

Tags: xorg, kali-linux, lenovo-laptop, nvidia-rtx

I cannot manage to have my second screen recognized by my laptop (Lenovo Legion 5).
It has Nvidia RTX 3060 and a second card :

```bash
❯ lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] [10de:2560] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] [17aa:3a81]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne [1002:1638] (rev c6)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cezanne [17aa:3a81]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

In  `update-alternatives`, the "current" is used:

```
❯ sudo update-alternatives --config nvidia
Il existe 2 choix pour l'alternative nvidia (qui fournit /usr/lib/nvidia/nvidia).

  Sélection   Chemin                     Priorité  État
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/nvidia/tesla-510   510       mode automatique
* 1            /usr/lib/nvidia/current     470       mode manuel
  2            /usr/lib/nvidia/tesla-510   510       mode manuel
```

Hashcat detect correctly CUDA:

```bash
❯ hashcat -I
hashcat (v6.2.5) starting in backend information mode

CUDA Info:
==========

CUDA.Version.: 11.4

Backend Device ID #1 (Alias: #2)
  Name...........: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU
  Processor(s)...: 30
  Clock..........: 1425
  Memory.Total...: 5946 MB
  Memory.Free....: 5838 MB
  PCI.Addr.BDFe..: 0000:01:00.0

OpenCL Info:
============

OpenCL Platform ID #1
  Vendor..: NVIDIA Corporation
  Name....: NVIDIA CUDA
  Version.: OpenCL 3.0 CUDA 11.4.231

  Backend Device ID #2 (Alias: #1)
    Type...........: GPU
    Vendor.ID......: 32
    Vendor.........: NVIDIA Corporation
    Name...........: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU
    Version........: OpenCL 3.0 CUDA
    Processor(s)...: 30
    Clock..........: 1425
    Memory.Total...: 5946 MB (limited to 1486 MB allocatable in one block)
    Memory.Free....: 5824 MB
    OpenCL.Version.: OpenCL C 1.2 
    Driver.Version.: 470.129.06
    PCI.Addr.BDF...: 01:00.0

OpenCL Platform ID #2
  Vendor..: The pocl project
  Name....: Portable Computing Language
  Version.: OpenCL 2.0 pocl 1.8  Linux, None+Asserts, RELOC, LLVM 11.1.0, SLEEF, DISTRO, POCL_DEBUG

  Backend Device ID #3
    Type...........: CPU
    Vendor.ID......: 1
    Vendor.........: AuthenticAMD
    Name...........: pthread-AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics
    Version........: OpenCL 1.2 pocl HSTR: pthread-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-generic
    Processor(s)...: 12
    Clock..........: 3300
    Memory.Total...: 11857 MB (limited to 2048 MB allocatable in one block)
    Memory.Free....: 5896 MB
    OpenCL.Version.: OpenCL C 1.2 pocl
    Driver.Version.: 1.8
```

I do not have any /etc/X11/xorg.conf file. If I generated one with `nvidia-xconfig`, I get a blinking cursor on reboot.

Switchable Graphics is enabled in BIOS.

When I connect the screen in HDMI, nothing happens ... And hotkeys Win+P or Fn+F7 does nothing.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

After several hours and mixing a lot of different ideas, I have just managed to get it to work and I deliver "my" solution. There is little black magic out there, but it worked on my side ...

1. Do not use Nvidia proprietary drivers (here nvidia-tesla510) or any other packages like optimus, prime, bumblebee, etc. To be safe: remove all current Nvidia drivers, without exception: `sudo apt purge nvidia-*`. If there is any error about dependency, remove it. Then reboot. Verify you do not have any Nvidia package installed on your system (Cuda included). Remove any superfluous packages with `apt autoremove`. I personnally advise to not install any package not officially distributed by the stable repositories. Reboot.
2. Follow the Kali install guide, basically:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y full-upgrade -y
[ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && sudo reboot -f
sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

3. For screen detections with the second screen connected: `xrandr -q`. You should see the second screen connected on the list. But, even with that, it was not sufficient to let the signal go through the second screen.
4. You can reboot now (maybe not useful - I know)
5. Write your own `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, inspired by: http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/375.39/README/randr14.html. Or you can use the package `nvidia-xconfig` (`apt install nvidia-xconfig`) then launch: `sudo nvidia-xconfig`. You can verify that a new file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is written. Here is mine:

```bash
❯ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 470.103.01

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "layout"
    Screen      0  "nvidia" 0 0
    Inactive       "amdgpu"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:01:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "amdgpu"
    Driver         "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "nvidia"
    Device         "nvidia"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "nvidia-auto-select"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "amdgpu"
    Device         "amdgpu"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
EndSection
```

If you have hybrid graphics based on Intel, you will have "intel" instead of "amdgpu".

6. Reboot, cross your fingers, and you are done. If it does not work (blinking cursor, black screen ...), go into another terminal (Alt+F2), remove the `xorg.conf`, reboot, and try to find another solution by continuing to blame Nvidia, Intel, AMD and your favorite manufacturer for their nice software support for Linux. Good luck.

Comment: I have an almost identical laptop (Lenovo Legion 5 with an AMD CPU and an Nvidia RTX GPU), and I had the same issue. Can confirm that your answer worked for me too :) Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

(Legion 5), Amd
press F9 to get into Bios setup menu and simply select discrete graphics card and reboot the system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but at the time of writing this post, I have tested and it did not work